# How do i configure server to find files three levels down in includes folder

Tags: php

First off, my development environment is XAMPP 1.8.2, (PHP 5.4.31), Windows 7,  Adobe Dreamweaver CS6.
What I want to do is include_once() files three levels down in Includes folder. E.g.  Includes/scripts/common_scripts/truncate_text.php
However, I'm getting the following error:

> Warning:
>   require_once('/Includes/scripts/common_scripts/truncate_text.php');
>   failed to open stream. No such file or directory in
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/My_site_revamped/index.php on line 10 Fatal error
>   require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/Includes/scripts/common_scripts/truncate_text.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\pear;') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\My_site_revamped\index.php on line 10 My_site files
>   worked perfectly on development environment but began throwing errors
>   when I uploaded to web server. So I cloned the root folder and renamed
>   it 'My_site_revamped' to address the errors without compromising the
>   original root folder.   Tried solutions: (1) include
>   $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .
>   "/Includes/scripts/common_scripts/truncate_text.php"; (2)
>   include(**DIR**. '/yourfile.php'.

I'm using shared hosting.
Thanks for looking into the problem

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is use `../` to take you back one directory. so for you to go back three directories use `../../../your-file.php`